# Referencing a JavaScript function in the onclick handler of a dynamically added element

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm spinning through a bunch of elements, and want to add a link which will run a short snippet of JavaScript. I'm doing this will a content script in a Chrome extension. The function `do_something` is defined in the same file as `my_func`, and is part of the Chrome extension.

`my_func` looks like this:

```
function my_func() {
    $(".matching_class").each(function() {
        $(this).html('<a href="javascript:do_something();">foo</a>');
    });
}
```

Problem is, when I click on my shiny links, I get this:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: `do_something` is not defined

How can I reference `do_something` from `my_func`?

Comment: Have you missed opening bracket ??
   
 `$(this).html('<a href="javascript:do_something();">foo</a>');`

Comment: @programmer_1 - nice spot, yes - I had, but not in my actual code, just the shortened example I posted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would probably be better practice to bind your function to the click event of the hyperlink rather than injecting a call to javascript: my_func();

Something along these lines (untested):

```
$(".matching_class").each(function() {
    $this.bind('click', do_something);
});
```

or with an anonymous function:

```
$(".matching_class").each(function() {
    $this.bind('click', function() {
        //do_somethintg code
    });
});
```

Comment: The anonymous function approach works for me - I can even call `do_something` from inside there and that seems to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to place `do_something` function before `my_func`.

It may be because of when you call do_something it may not find my_func as it is defined after my_func.

As A **JavaScript engine is an interpreter** that interprets JavaScript source code and executes the script accordingly.